# Is it possible to embed webapp functionality into a map using google maps?

Tags: ios, google-maps, web-applications, cordova, google-maps-api-3

Okay, so we have an app written in objective-c for iOS. My job is to rewrite it using html/css/javascript and phonegap as a multiplatform app for ios and android.

Part of the existing objective-c app works like this: you select an item off a list, and it loads an embedded map from ios's built-in maps (not google maps) and puts a marker on the map where that item is. You can tap on the marker and it brings up a little info box with a button to "See more info," which if pressed takes you to a separate part of the app with information regarding the item.

This is the part I'm trying to get working in html/css right now, and I don't even know if that's possible.

So here's my question: can that be done using the google maps api, the whole embedding functionality into the map? i need that little info box which brings me back to the app; that's the crucial portion. Does anyone know whether this is possible, and whether there are any good references, examples, or tutorials to help out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In the Google Maps API you can add Markers.
2. You can add a "click" event listener to the Marker where you can then open an InfoWindow.
3. In the InfoWindow, you can place some HTML, including a link or button that invokes a JavaScript function that will take you to the next screen of your web app.